# Vue3 webcam typescript support

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, webcam

i'm looking for component webcam for my vue3 project, currently i found https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-camera-lib this package, but the problem is this package don't support typescript, i got this error when i try to import to my project

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Z0P.png)

```
import { WebCamUI } from 'vue-camera-lib'
```

I'm thinking about 2 approach :

1. add type for that library but i don't know how to start
2. using similar library with typescript support but i cannot find one

Any help will appreciate, thankyou

i expect can solve the type support issue, or find similar library that i can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supporting TypeScript doesn't prevent use of the library.  Remember, TypeScript doesn't run in the browser, JavaScript does, so TypeScript errors/warnings aren't usually blockers as long as the transpiled JavaScript is still sound. The error's suggestion is enough to correct the issue when it says:

> ... or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-camera-lib';`

Simply add to any existing `.dt.s` file or create new one, e.g. `index.d.ts`:

```js
declare module 'vue-camera-lib'
```

After saving, the error will no longer appear.